# Could the assign function for containers possibly overflow?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, containers

I ran into this question today and thought I should post it for the community's reference and/or opinions.

The standard C++ containers vector, deque, list, and string provide an `assign` member function.  There are two versions; I'm primarily interested in the one accepting an iterator range.  The [Josuttis book](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/) is a little ambiguous with its description.  From p. 237...

> Assigns all elements of the range [beg,end); this is, is replaces all existing elements with copies of the elements of [beg,end).

It doesn't say what happens if the size of the assignee container is different from the range being assigned.  Does it truncate?  Does it automagically expand?  Is it undefined behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found.  It turns out I didn't have to worry about silently doing the wrong thing.  Once again, the standard has the answer.  From section 23.2.6.1:

> `void assign(Iter first, Iter last);`
>
> Effects:
>
> `erase(begin(), end());`
>
> `insert(begin(), first, last);`

So it's really just a shortcut for a `clear()` followed by an `insert` of the full range.

Comment: Was just typing it up. :) To make it clearer, `assign` might have been called "`reassign`", to make it clear the contents of the container are being completely reassigned.